# Get class in other element .closest() or parent() using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem that for experts is very simple.

I do looping on some html tags like the following snippet:

```
// looping
<div class="toggle m-toggle-accordian">
    <p class="i-want-to-get-this" id="biaya-123">Biaya Admin 0%</p>
    <p>Rp 5000</p>
</div>
<div class="collapse m-coll-air-unselected">
    <div class="m-offer-detail">
        <div class="col-xs-8 m-offer-caption">Cicilan per Bulan</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 m-offer-amount">Rp 4000</div>
    </div>
    <div class="m-offer-detail">
        <div class="button-click">Pilih</div>
    </div>
</div>
// end looping
```

I want to when clicking button with class 'button-click' want to get id value from class 'i-want-to-get-this'.

I tried using .find () but have not succeeded.

```
$(this).find('.i-want-to-get-this').attr('id');
```

Comment: Try this $($(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.i-want-to-get-this')[0]).attr('id');

Comment: Why do you use `$(this)` ? Take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Comment: I added my answer please have a look

Comment: Thanks @NanditaAroraSharma this work.

Comment: Thanks @Med, I will read more references again

Comment: You are welcome @WisnuPramonoE.S :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$($(".button-click").parent().parent().parent().find('.m-toggle-accordian .i-want-to-get-this')[0]).attr('id')` to target the required element

```js
$(document).on("click", ".button-click", function() {

  console.log($($(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.m-toggle-accordian .i-want-to-get-this')[0]).attr('id'));

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle m-toggle-accordian">
  <p class="i-want-to-get-this" id="biaya-123">Biaya Admin 0%</p>
  <p>Rp 5000</p>
</div>
<div class="collapse m-coll-air-unselected">
  <div class="m-offer-detail">
    <div class="col-xs-8 m-offer-caption">Cicilan per Bulan</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 m-offer-amount">Rp 4000</div>
  </div>
  <div class="m-offer-detail">
    <div class="button-click">Click me</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is correct answer but I still think `$(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.m-toggle-accordian .i-want-to-get-this')[0]).attr('id')` is way too long to get the data.

Comment: Sorry I want to ask. what is the meaning [0] in the script console.log($($(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.m-toggle-accordian .i-want-to-get-this')[0]).attr('id')); ? is it an array? what if I want to get it dynamically? so when I use $ (this) it will automatically refer to the desired array.

Comment: .find returns an array of elements, as you know there is  only one element in that array so you can safely use [0] index to refer to that element

Comment: @Natsathorn Is there a more practical way? please share it

Comment: check my answer it do similar thing, longer but more readable.

Answer (score 2):

I just realize that's you are looping create elements so I think you need to add some more code like this.

So when you are looping for create an element why don't you add a value to as a button attribute

```
<div class="button-click" data-elementId="biaya-123">Pilih</div>
```

Then you can easy get with jquery

```
$('.button-click').click(function () {
    var myId = $(this).data('elementId'); // to get the target element ID
    var targetElement = $('#' + myId); // to get the targetElement
})
```

Comment: I think he's got multiple elements to click and multiple elements with the classname "i-want-to-get-this".

Comment: Actually I want to get an element of the class 'i-want-to-get-this'. And the problem is because the html tag position is not as usual I encountered. btw thanks for the help

Comment: So you could do it with one more line of code I will added for you

Comment: @WisnuPramonoE.S Added

Comment: @Natsathorn Thanks,, i will try

Answer (score 2):

Get id from Class using below code

```js
$('.button-click').click(function(){
    alert($('.i-want-to-get-this').attr('id'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle m-toggle-accordian">
            <p class="i-want-to-get-this" id="biaya-123">Biaya Admin 0%</p>
            <p>Rp 5000</p>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse m-coll-air-unselected">
            <div class="m-offer-detail">
                <div class="col-xs-8 m-offer-caption">Cicilan per Bulan</div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 m-offer-amount">Rp 4000</div>
            </div>
            <div class="m-offer-detail">
                <div class="button-click">Pilih</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".button-click").on("click", function(){
 console.log( $(this).parents(".m-coll-air-unselected").prev(".m-toggle-accordian").find(".i-want-to-get-this").attr("id") );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle m-toggle-accordian">
  <p class="i-want-to-get-this" id="biaya-123">Biaya Admin 0%</p>
  <p>Rp 5000</p>
</div>
<div class="collapse m-coll-air-unselected">
  <div class="m-offer-detail">
    <div class="col-xs-8 m-offer-caption">Cicilan per Bulan</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 m-offer-amount">Rp 4000</div>
  </div>
  <div class="m-offer-detail">
    <div class="button-click">Click me</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="toggle m-toggle-accordian">
  <p class="i-want-to-get-this" id="biaya-123">Foo Bar 0%</p>
  <p>Rp 5000</p>
</div>
<div class="collapse m-coll-air-unselected">
  <div class="m-offer-detail">
    <div class="col-xs-8 m-offer-caption">Element 2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 m-offer-amount">foo bar</div>
  </div>
  <div class="m-offer-detail">
    <div class="button-click">Click me 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:  https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/BPKbGP

```
$('.button-click').on('click', function(e){      
  console.log($(this).parents('.m-coll-air-unselected').prev('div').find('.i-want-to-get-this').attr('id'))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by creating parent element, like this :-

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="toggle m-toggle-accordian">
  <p class="i-want-to-get-this" id="biaya-123">Biaya Admin 0%</p>
  ...
 </div>
 <div class="collapse m-coll-air-unselected">
 ...
  <div class="m-offer-detail">
   <div class="button-click">Pilih</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.button-click').click(function() {
 $(this).parents('.parent').find('.i-want-to-get-this').attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

We don't know if "i-want-to-get-this" class name is unique and since we are talking about loops it's better not to jump outside the looped tags. We can move between tags with `$.closest()` and `$.prev()`

This is still bad practice, because we are risking to brake the functionality. If someone inputs additional tag into the loop then function probably not work

Edit: If we assume the div tag with class "toggle" is constant we can also set .prev('.toggle') so we will minimize the possibility of getting other ids.

I'm going to suggest you to add data-id or similar data attribute on your button 
like: `<button data-id='my-id-1' class="button-click">Click me</button>`
Then you can simply use `$(this).data('id')`

```js
$(document).on("click", ".button-click", function() {

  console.log($(this).closest('.collapse').prev().find('.i-want-to-get-this').first().attr('id'));

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle m-toggle-accordian">
  <p class="i-want-to-get-this" id="i_got_id_1">Biaya Admin 0%</p>
  <p>Rp 5000</p>
</div>
<div class="collapse m-coll-air-unselected">
  <div class="m-offer-detail">
    <div class="col-xs-8 m-offer-caption">Cicilan per Bulan 1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 m-offer-amount">Rp 4000</div>
  </div>
  <div class="m-offer-detail">
    <button class="button-click">Click me</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="toggle m-toggle-accordian">
  <p class="i-want-to-get-this" id="i_got_id_2">Biaya Admin 1%</p>
  <p>Rp 5000</p>
</div>
<div class="collapse m-coll-air-unselected">
  <div class="m-offer-detail">
    <div class="col-xs-8 m-offer-caption">Cicilan per Bulan 2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 m-offer-amount">Rp 4001</div>
  </div>
  <div class="m-offer-detail">
    <button class="button-click">Click me</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="toggle m-toggle-accordian">
  <p class="i-want-to-get-this" id="i_got_id_3">Biaya Admin 113%</p>
  <p>Rp 5000</p>
</div>
<div class="collapse m-coll-air-unselected">
  <div class="m-offer-detail">
    <div class="col-xs-8 m-offer-caption">Cicilan per Bulan 3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 m-offer-amount">Rp 7000</div>
  </div>
  <div class="m-offer-detail">
    <button class="button-click">Click me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @sulest. Your answer is good and complete for the case I am facing.